# Partial SSA in LLVM

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I came across this concept of partial SSA in LLVM where LLVM identifies two classes of variables: (1) top-level variables are those that cannot be referenced indirectly via a
pointer, i.e., those whose address is never exposed via the address-of operator or returned via a dynamic memory allocation;
(2) address-taken variables are those that have had their address exposed and therefore can be indirectly referenced via a pointer

This definition is verbatim from [This paper](https://llvm.org/pubs/2009-01-POPL-PointerAnalysis.pdf).

The paper further explains with an example that I can't seem to wrap my head around.

Is there an easier example for this or maybe any other resource I can look into?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Either a variable can be changed by writing to a pointer, or it can't because the code has no pointer to that variable. What's the problem?

Comment: The authors are referring to the fact that LLVM's registers are SSA while the memory is not. LLVM has no address-of operator at all, but it does have ways to allocate memory, the pointer to which goes into a register. Registers are always in SSA form but in-memory storage can mutate (through a store instruction) and is therefore not singly-assigned. Hence, a "partial" SSA. In C terms `int v;` allocates memory on the stack, but if you never take `v`s address then it can be promoted to a register, at which point it must be in SSA form.

Comment: Maybe https://nccbulletin.ru/files/article/gurchenkov.pdf ? Or https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/lin/cs380c/handout09.pdf ?

Answer (score 0):

To understand about partial SSA, it is good to keep the SSA form in mind. In partial SSA form, we represent only the top level variables in SSA form. The address-taken variables are never explicitly represented (hence, the name partial SSA). An address taken variable is only accessed via the top-level variables that point to it. Typically these accesses happen via LOAD and STORE instructions. Also, the link between the address taken variable and the top level variable is established typically via an ALLOC instruction.

Take the example given in Figure 1 of the mentioned paper. In that example, w, x, y and z are top-level variables and a, b, c and d are address-taken variables. Thus, we notice w_1, x_1, y_1, z_1, y_2 and z_2, which are all SSA form representations of w, x, y and z. Whenever, we have instructions involving address-taken variables, we see ALLOCs, LOADs and STOREs based on the corresponding top-level variables. The address taken variables are never explicitly represented in SSA form. Also, as shown in Figure 2 of the same paper, new temporary variables could be introduced, in order to achieve this partial SSA form.